# Symfony2 Add data_collector tag in compiler pass

Tags: php, symfony

It seems I am unable to get a data collector to load through a compiler pass. I am attempting to keep the data collector optional to enable. It is defined in a YAML file without the tag, then the compiler pass adds the tag based on a parameter setting.

It seems maybe a compiler pass is too late to add the tag?

```
<?php
    if ($container->getParameter('git_data_collector_enabled')) {
        $gitDataCollectorDef = $container->getDefinition('git_data_collector');

        $gitDataCollectorDef->addTag('data_collector', array(
            'template' => 'Profiler:git_info_layout',
            'id' => 'git',
        ));
    }
```

Comment: How about initializing the whole data collector in the compiler pass whether or not `git_data_collector_enabled` is true?

Answer (score 0):

The `data_collector` tag is used in the [symfony framework bundle profiler pass](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ProfilerPass.php). The compiler pass' in the symfony framework bundle are more than likely run before your compiler pass because you will have probably registered the framework bundle near the top of your list in the app kernel before your bundle (and bundles are loaded in that order).

This means unfortunately it is too late to use the `data_collector` tag.  However you can still manipulate the profiler service before it is instantiated and add your `git_data_collector` to it using the `addMethodCall` method on the profiler definition:

```
if ($container->getParameter('git_data_collector_enabled')) {
    //Get the profiler definition
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('profiler');
    //require the definition to run the add method with a reference to your data collector when it is instantiated
    $definition->addMethodCall('add', array(new Reference('git_data_collector')));

    //Add your template to the data_collector templates
    $templates = $container->getParameter('data_collector.templates');
    $container->setParameter('data_collector.templates', array_merge($templates,array('git' => array('git', 'Profiler:git_info_layout'))));
}
```

The idea is from the [profiler compiler pass](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ProfilerPass.php) as your are essentially trying to replicate some of it's functionality.